# Perl regex hitting condition when not matching

Tags: regex, perl

I am checking a status of a program and acting apon it.

So I either receive **all**, **local** or an **error**.

However upon checking it with my `regex` I am always hitting the condition even when it doesn't match.

```
    if ($pri !~ /local/ || $pri !~ /all/) {
            print $pri."\n";
            print "[PRIMARY] Heartbeat is not responding correctly \n";
            $status++;
    }
```

Above print displays as:

```
perl test.pl -p xx.xx.xx.xx -s xx.xx.xx.xx
all
[PRIMARY] Heartbeat is not responding correctly
```

And a dump looks like

```
perl test.pl -p xx.xx.xx.xx -s xx.xx.xx.xx
$VAR1 = 'all';
[PRIMARY] Heartbeat is not responding correctly
```

Am I missing something obvious? To me the condition should be skipped as the value is **all**.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, although down voting because of some grammatical errors is pretty lame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regexp is almost fine, you just used wrong logical operator - or. It should be and:

```
if ($pri !~ /local/ && $pri !~ /all/) {
    ...
```

Also for regexp consider surrounding by ^ and $ to have full string match.

Comment: I just realised this as you answered it. The simple things eh? Appreciated.